# First derivative and second derivative maximums

Tags: calculus

If $f'(5)=0$ and $f''(5)=0$,
 what can you say about $f$?

$a)$ At $x=5$, $f$ has a local maximum.

$b)$ At $x=5$, $f$ has a local minimum.

$c)$ At $x=5$, $f$ has neither a maximum nor a minimum.

$d)$ More information is needed to determine if $f$ has a maximum or minimum at $x=5$.

I am confused about what can be said about the second derivative and first derivative both being $0$ at a point.

Comment: We need more information about $f$, lets consider the following functions
$f(x)=-(x-5)^4,\qquad g(x)=(x-5)^4,\qquad\text{and}\qquad h(x)=(x-5)^3$ each one satisfies the conditions stated above.

Answer (score 1):

It has a point of inflection at x=0 with a tangent parallel to x-axis. E.g., y = x^3

Answer (score 0):

Nothing can be about local extremum :

- $f(x) = x^4$ verify $f'(0)=f''(0)=0$ and has a local minimum at 0
- $g(x) = - x^4$ verify $g'(0)=g''(0)=0$ and has a local maximum at 0
- $h(x) = x^5$ verify $h'(0)=h''(0)=0$ and has not a local extremum at 0

Comment: How about for when f'(1)=0, and f"(1)=1? This would mean its a minimum right?